# Office 365 Graph API Call from PS stopped working ( SSPR)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I used to download usercredentialusagedetails through PS and it used to work fine until few weeks ago and now it fails.

Request : GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/userCredentialUsageDetails

More Details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-usercredentialusagedetails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Error : Invoke-RestMethod : {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#reports/userCredentialUsageDetails","v alue":[{"id":"79876725968494393786570221953037561096003605792378637660218099476724503735617","feature":"registration"{ "error": { "code": "InternalServerError", "message": "The property 'userPrincipalName[Nullable=False]' of type 'Edm.String' has a null value, which is not allowed.", "innerError": { "date": "2020-09-30T11:58:11", "request-id": "60bdc1d7-054f-402b-8054-e0c8db709e43", "client-request-id": "60bdc1d7-054f-402b-8054-e0c8db709e43" } } }

i  have number of other queries/requests in same script and they all work fine.
Can someone pls try in their tenancy? is anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: I was also able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is resolved. I have got the confirmation on this [Github Link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10182). Looks like it could be an issue on the server end and its resolved now.